# How much space will be actually allocated in a table if the value for char field is null in Django postgresql database?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, database-design, model

I am using Postgresql database with Django. Now suppose I have a model(table) with three fields:

```
class TempModel(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(_('Url'), blank=True, null=True, max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(_('File'), upload_to=custom_file_path, null=True, blank=True, max_length=1024)
    order = models.IntegerField(_('Order'), blank=False, null=False)
```

Now if I don't provide any value in URL and file field, then null values will be stored in those fields. And null takes around 1 bytes of memory. But the max memory limit is 100 chars and 1024 chars respectively.

> So my doubt is, How much space will be allocated for the URL and file field if I don't provide any input data? Will there be any wastage of memory in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL values don't take up any storage space in the database.

If a table has nullable columns, each table row has a *null bitmap* that signifies which columns are NULL. Of course this bitmap occupies storage, but it does so regardless if there are NULL values or not.

Comment: So Does PostgreSQL can store unlimited amount of characters if we don't specify the max length of char field?

Comment: The limit is 1GB.